# How can I control the position of this sled motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I got this sled from an old 1999 Toshiba CDROM Drive.
I was expecting a stepper motor controllingthe sled.  But it uses a DC motor with two wires.
It seems to me that the positioning of the sled is controlled by two sensors disposed below the first gear.  Can anybody give me a hint how the motor control is performed?
Thanks.

[image: are the two chips below the first gear with the black ring Hall sensors?]

Comment: Are you sure that the sensor is not simply an "end-stop" sense? Motor control is usually a very complex dual-loop servo derived from the optical track detector in the scanning head.

Comment: @glen_geek that first gear is going to rotate faster than the big one, and I'd be surprised if the big one wasn't doing multiple rotations as well. In that case it would seem more likely those two sensors are part of a quadrature encoder, probably optical or magnetic (I'm guessing optical and the black/white parts on the gear have something to do with it).

Comment: @Jon that might be the case, but only for approximate seeking, the *fine* control is going to use the tracks on the CD rather than information from the sled.

Comment: @Jon, the big wheel is not making a full rotation. 
Since I cant find any optical components, yet, I assume it's magnetically encoded.

Comment: don't assume anything ... look for *end of travel* sensors for the sled ..... most CDROM drives close the tray when the tray is in the open position and is pushed a little by hand... look for a sensor that would detect that slight movement ... that would be the open *end of travel* sensor